# How to loop through chained methods with dynamic data?

Tags: javascript, methods, chained, fluent-ffmpeg

Using `fluent-ffmpeg`, I have a dynamic list of videos I am trying to stitch together using Node. The below code works but was manually hard-written in. How would I turn this into a loop with the chained function?

I looked into `eval()` and couldn't get that to work, and not sure if chained promises is what I'm looking for (not exactly sure what to do here).

```
ffmpeg()
  .input('video/video_after0.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after1.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after2.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after3.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after4.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after5.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after6.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after7.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after8.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after9.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after10.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after11.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after12.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after13.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after14.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after15.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after16.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after17.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after18.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after19.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after20.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after21.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after22.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after23.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after24.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after25.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after26.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after27.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after28.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after29.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after30.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after31.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after32.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after33.mp4')
  .input('video/video_after34.mp4')

  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('An error occurred while merging video files: ' + err.message);
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    logger.info('****** STEP 6 ENDED ******');
    callback(null);
  })
  .mergeToFile('video/video_after.mp4', '/video/temp');
```

Here is my attempt at using `eval()` but it doesn't work:

```
  var ffmpegInputCommand = "ffmpeg()";

  // For Loop to create the ffmpeg().input() command for multiple inputs:
  async.forEach(array, function(data, done) {
    if (data.id < array.length - 1) {
      ffmpegInputCommand += ".input('" + videoAfter + data.id + ".mp4')";
    }
    done();
  }, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else {
      eval(ffmpegInputCommand).on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('An error occurred while merging video files: ' + err.message);
      })
      .on('end', function() {
        logger.info('****** STEP 6 ENDED ******');
        callback(null);
      })
      .mergeToFile('video/video_after.mp4', '/video/temp');
    }
  });
  // End: For-Loop
}
```

The variables were defined prior to this above code.

Comment: Please show your attempt at trying to use a loop and explain why/how it didn't work.  Right now, your question is just asking someone to write the loop code for you.

Comment: I've updated with my `eval` attempt

Comment: Alright, now why do you think you need to use `eval()`?

Comment: Not sure how to dynamically create chained methods with this API's limitations -- after researching, it looked like `eval()` could be a good solution, but I wasn't sure if my eval code was overkill and there was a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not making a simple loop?

```
start = 0;
max = 35;
while (start < max) {
  fname = 'video/video_after'+str(start)+'.mp4'
  ffmpeg().input(fname)
  start += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to chain `input()` to the return value or the preceding `input()` I would suggest using a [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).  You most definately don't need to use `eval()`.

1. Construct an array of the files that you want to concatenate.
2. `reduce()` them onto `ffmpeg()`
3. Attach your subscribers as you do normally
4. Chain the `mergeToFile()` call.

Consider the following:

```
let files = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 34; i++) {
    files.push(`video/video_after${i}.mp4`);
}

files
    .reduce((prev, curr) => prev.input(curr), ffmpeg())
    .on("error", err => console.log(`An error occurred while merging video files: ${err.message}`))
    .on("end", () => {
        logger.info("****** STEP 6 ENDED ******");
        callback(null);
    })
    .mergeToFile('video/video_after.mp4', '/video/temp');
```

I think your hang up is "how do I construct a dynamic list of varying strings".  You use loops and string concatenation or even template literals per my example above.  I'm not sure where `callback` is defined, but I assume that is working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

If it has to chain for certain reasons, you could try something like the following:

```
var i = 0;
var ffmpeg = ffmpeg();
while (i < 35) {
    ffmpeg = ffmpeg.input('video/video_after'+str(start)+'.mp4');
    i++;
}

ffmpeg.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('An error occurred while merging video files: ' + err.message);
})
.on('end', function() {
    logger.info('****** STEP 6 ENDED ******');
    callback(null);
})
.mergeToFile('video/video_after.mp4', '/video/temp');
```